# Cannot call method "getRange" of null. (line 20, file "Code")

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

TypeError: Cannot call method "getRange" of null. (line 20, file "Code")
My script is running as I want it to, but I continue to get the above error. The script has a trigger to run when a form is completed it runs moves the data, then then returns the above error.
[Here is the sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1B93n7wQ8rosmcaqlpgD9FoL1KWfbXALrror7t6r5K2M/edit#gid=353987993)

Line 20 is

```
    var data = sourceSpreadSheetSheetID.getRange(2, 1,sourceSpreadSheetSheetID.getLastRow()-1, sourceSpreadSheetSheetID.getLastColumn()).getValues();
```

I have checked sheet names and made adjustments, but seem to be missing something.

```
    function CopyDataToNewFile() {

// How Many Columns over to copy
var columsCopyCount = 4; // A=1 B=2 C=3 ....

// What Column to Monitor
var columnsToMonitor = 3; // A=1 B=2 C=3 ....MONITORS In or Out

//TARGET SPREAD SHEETS
var HallPass = "Hall_Pass"
var CheckOut = "Out";
var CheckIn = "In";

//SOURCE SPREAD SHEET
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1B93n7wQ8rosmcaqlpgD9FoL1KWfbXALrror7t6r5K2M'); //Need ID from Form response sheet
var sourceSpreadSheetSheetID = ss.getSheetByName(HallPass);
var sourceSpreadSheetSheetID1 = ss.getSheetByName(CheckOut);
var sourceSpreadSheetSheetID2 = ss.getSheetByName(CheckIn);

var data = sourceSpreadSheetSheetID.getRange(2, 1,sourceSpreadSheetSheetID.getLastRow()-1, sourceSpreadSheetSheetID.getLastColumn()).getValues();

var Out = [];
var In = [];


for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

    var rValue = data[i][2];

    if (rValue == CheckOut) {
        Out.push(data[i]);
    } else if (rValue == CheckIn) {
        In.push(data[i]);

    }
}

if(Out.length > 0){
  sourceSpreadSheetSheetID1.getRange(sourceSpreadSheetSheetID1.getLastRow() + 1, 1, Out.length, Out[0].length).setValues(Out);
  sourceSpreadSheetSheetID.deleteRows(2,sourceSpreadSheetSheetID.getLastRow() - 1);
}

if(In.length > 0){
   sourceSpreadSheetSheetID2.getRange(sourceSpreadSheetSheetID2.getLastRow() + 1, 1, In.length, In[0].length).setValues(In);
   sourceSpreadSheetSheetID.deleteRows(2,sourceSpreadSheetSheetID.getLastRow() -1);
}}
```

I would like this script to run without errors

Answer (score 1):

So the code looks like it should run, as the error you are getting is about `sourceSpreadSheetSheetID` being a *null value*, so when I checked the spreadsheet you posted I noticed that the sheet you refer to as "HallPass" is actually called "**Hall_Pass**". In your code, instead of passing in the variable `HallPass` you are giving it a string `"HallPass"`. This is causing the issue.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1B93n7wQ8rosmcaqlpgD9FoL1KWfbXALrror7t6r5K2M'); //Need ID from Form response sheet
var sourceSpreadSheetSheetID = ss.getSheetByName(HallPass); //Sheet name was incorrect.
// Did you mean to leave out the Quotations to refer to the variable above?
var sourceSpreadSheetSheetID1 = ss.getSheetByName(CheckOut);
var sourceSpreadSheetSheetID2 = ss.getSheetByName(CheckIn);
```

Comment: I believe that I made the recommended changes correctly, but I am still getting the same error. I have made changes to original post to reflect the changes.

Comment: @JeremyHunter That is weird. Are you sure it's the same error and not referring to a different line?

Comment: This is the error sent to me.                                                                           
 2/11/19 10:00 AM CopyDataToNewFile The coordinates or dimensions of the range are invalid. (line 19, file "Code") formSubmit 2/11/19 10:00 AM

Comment: @JeremyHunter That is a different error about the same line. What does the sheet setup look like? The error is pretty clear here.

Comment: thank you was not paying attention saw the same line made the assumption. I have not changed anything with sheet not sure what would cause this error.